# for namespaced js modules are non-namespaced file names normally used?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, javascript-namespaces

For namespaced js modules are non-namespaced file names normally used?  C# class filenames, for example, usually reflect only the basic class name as opposed to the fully namespaced class name. So, for example, a UserManager class with namespace Acme.Administration.UserManager would typically have a file name of UserManager.cs. Is this the typical pattern used for Javascript as well?  Not sure I see any benefit to including the js module namespace in the js module file name?

Answer (score 0):

Actually JavaScript modules work like namespaces themselves. They're not meant to work in a *one export per file*.

In fact, ES2015 and newer standards own no concept of spanning modules across many files, because *a file is a module*.

Thus, it seems that you need to change your mind about how to work with JavaScript.

Anyway, you could use a NPM script or task runners like Grunt/Gulp to glue multiple files into a single one so you can still develop on multiple files but really you're implementing a single module file.

In terms of how to organize your project, usually you would create a directory per *area*. For example:

- users

  - managers.js
  - entities.js
- shared

  - stringHelpers.js
  - http.js

BTW, there's no standard or any actual benefit on following a concrete approach on this matter. Your best bet is to define a convention and use it everywhere in order to make your source code directory structure very predictable.